# Could not find default endpoint element error in Allscripts

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to connect to a WCF service.  The service reference resides in a class library. I am successful connecting to the service in my MSTEST unit test by adding an App.config to the unit test project.  I am unsuccessful connecting to the service in the application.  I found the application's configuration file.  I am able to edit the file and I confirmed that I can access keys I added to the configuration via

`<add key="testKey"`

However, when I try to connect in the application I receive error

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ContractName.Service' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.  This might be because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I added the section

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPinGenerator" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                     maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                         realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://somewhere"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPinGenerator"
             contract="CompanyNamePinGenerator.IPinGenerator" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPinGenerator" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Yet, it does not fix the problem.  I also tried adding the namespace to `contract=""` and to the generated code attribute

`[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName=`

Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

Comment: There are several related topics suggested over on the right that sound like they might help you troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that CompanyNamePinGenerator.IPinGenerator in the contract attribute of your endpoint is exactly correct?  And that the server side endpoint at the exact address you provided is a basicHttpBinding?

Comment: Copying the entire <system.serviceModel> section from your mstest app.config into your application's config file should be enough to get things working (assuming there isn't already a system.serviceModel section).I'd suggest opening up your config file with the SvcConfigEditor.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009(v=vs.100).aspx) to validate the various references to bindings and configuration are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you don't have any endpoint in the client configuration matching the name `ContractName.Service`.

All I see is you have only one endpoint with a different contract `CompanyNamePinGenerator.IPinGenerator`.

Your service class or interface sitting in the proxy file references the `ContractName.Service` and that's missing in the config.

You have to make sure couple of things:

1. Update the generated proxy to the latest
2. Make sure the client configuration contains all the endpoints required by the services.

Normally when I face this kind of issues, I open the VS command prompt run the svcutil.exe  and copy the proxy code and client configuration from the generated files.